# JSON data works as string but throws internal error when object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using an AJAX post like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AJAXServices.aspx/" + method,
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            successfunc();
        },
        error: function(data) {
            errorfunc();
        }
    });
```

When I use the variable "params" like this:

```
var params = '{"QuestionID":"' + UpdateQuestion_ID + '", "NewText":"' + newText + '"}';
```

It works.

But when I change it to this:

```
var params = { QuestionID: UpdateQuestion_ID, NewText: newText };
```

This throws an internal server error on the server side:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Server side method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void UpdateQuestion(string QuestionID, string NewText)
    {
        ....
     }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the first case `params` is a string and in the second case `params` is an object.

I guess the server expects a valid json string. Make sure `params` is an object and use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert it to a valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string before sending it.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    ...
});
```

Comment: Works. Thanks @rckrd

Answer (score 1):

A JavaScript Object and a JSON looks very similar but have minor difference.

A valid JSON must have key wrapped inside "" but a JS Object Key can be written without "".

Below example is a **Valid JS Object but Invalid JSON** :

> {
>     name: "Ravi",
>     country: "India"
>   }

So, below is a Valid JSON for same :

> {
>     "name": "Ravi",
>     "country": "India"
>   }

Further, Server Side , it would break as it is a InValid JSON.

You can validate your JSON at http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Note : You can convert any JS Object to Valid JSON using

> JSON.stringify(JavaScript_Object);

Example :

> var a = { name: "Ravi", country: "India" }

Convert from JS-Obj to JSON

> var b = JSON.stringify(a);

Now, var b is a valid JSON.

> Output : "{"name":"Ravi","country":"India"}"